# Leap year functionality in Ruby and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ruby, datetime

I did a line-by-line translation and am wondering if the JavaScript code looks idiomatic.

Original Ruby code:

```ruby
class Year
  def initialize(number)
    @number = number
  end

  def leap?
    divisible_by?(400) || ( divisible_by?(4) && !divisible_by?(100))
  end

  private
  def divisible_by?(a_number)
    @number % a_number == 0
  end  
end
```

JavaScript Implementation looks like this:

```js
var Year = function( number ) {      
  this.number = number;    
  function isLeap() {
    return isDivisibleBy(400) || ( isDivisibleBy(4) && !isDivisibleBy(100));
  }
  function isDivisibleBy(a_number) {
    return this.number % a_number == 0
  }        
  return isLeap();
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, the two pieces of code are not equivalent, so definitely not idiomatic. Javascript does not have classes like other languages, so it has a unique way of creating class equivalents.

Let's look at what your Javascript code *does* first, so we can understand how to fix it.

> ```
> var Year = function( number ) {
> ```

Going ok so far. We could also simply declare `Year` as a function: `function Year(number) {...`, but this is acceptable.

> ```
>   this.number = number;
> ```

Also good. When we say `new Year(2014)`, we'll assign it to the `number` property of the instance.

> ```
>   function isLeap() {
>     return isDivisibleBy(400) || ( isDivisibleBy(4) && !isDivisibleBy(100));
>   }
> ```

Ok, so the method body is fine, but this is not being assigned as a method on the object, so we won't be able to do something like `yearInstance.isLeap()`. Instead, `isLeap` can only be used from the context of this method.

> ```
>   function isDivisibleBy(a_number) {
>     return this.number % a_number == 0
>   }
> ```

This is meant to be a private method. Unfortunately, Javascript does not have a traditional concept of private scope. More on this later.

> ```
>   return isLeap();
> }
> ```

This return statement is...tricky. In Javascript, we can return an object from a constructor, and the value returned would be that object and not an instance of the function we are instantiating. I'll admit, that's confusing. Here's an example:

```
function A() {
    return new B();
}
```

Now, if we call `new A()`, we actually get back a new `B`. **But** there are caveats. If the return value is not an object (so a primitive like a boolean or a number not boxed), then we will **not** get back the return value, we'll get the object we are trying to instantiate. So now back to your code. From the constructor, we return the result of a call to `isLeap`. First, `isLeap` is not being called on any object, so it will always return false. Because false is a primitive, the result is discarded, and we end up exactly with what we expect. Because of the trickiness of Javascript constructors and returns, even if we get what we want, we should *still* not have a return statement. It is inappropriate in a constructor, and can lead to unexpected bugs. For more, see [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1978474).

---

Now we can break this code down to be more idiomatic.

```
function Year(number) {
    this.number = number;
}

Year.prototype.isLeap = function() {
    return this.isDivisibleBy(400) || (this.isDivisibleBy(4) && !this.isDivisibleBy(100));
}

Year.prototype.isDivisibleBy = function(aNumber) {
    return this.number % aNumber === 0;
}
```

Here, we've broken out the methods from the constructor. Because Javascript is a prototypical language, we create methods by adding them to the prototype of the constructor, `Year.prototype` in this case. We see `isLeap` is now a property on the `Year` prototype, meaning we can now call it like `yearInstance.isLeap()`. `isDivisibleBy` is also a property on the `Year` prototype. This means that, here, it's a public method as well. Like I said before, Javascript does not have the same concept of private visibility.

We can't make a private method as a property on the object. There are a few ways around this. The simplest is to prepend the method name with an underscore (like `Year.prototype._isDivisibleBy`). This does not make the method uncallable, but is a common convention to indicate that the method is meant to be private.

An alternate way (which I am not going to show) is to use a closure to hide the function.

Inside `isLeap`, all of the calls to `isDivisibleBy` must now be prefixed with `this.` because it is now a method.

Inside `isDivisibleBy`, we now see `==` is replaced with `===`. This is not required in any way, and can sometimes boil down to personal preference (see [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/lint.html#eqeq)). Basically, it compares value *and* type when checking for equality. Also, `a_number` has been changed to `aNumber`. Generally, I find that Javascript following similar camelCasing conventions as Java.

Answer (score 3):

Since cbojar didn't want to show a solution with closures I will do.

```
function Year(number) {
 // Check number here

 function isDivisibleBy(aNumber) {
  return number % aNumber === 0;
 };

 return {
  get year() { return number; },
  get isLeap() {
    return isDivisibleBy(400) || (isDivisibleBy(4) && !isDivisibleBy(100));
  }
 }
};
```

You can access `isLeap` as property.

```
var currentYear = new Year(new Date().getFullYear());
> currentYear.isLeap;
false
> currentYear.year;
2014
```

The use of closures hides the `isDivisibleBy` function and prevents anybody from changing the year.

```
> // isDivisibleBy is not accessible from outside
> currentYear.isDivisibleBy(0);
TypeError: undefined is not a function
> // Cannot change year
> currentYear.year = 2000;
2000
> currentYear.year;
2014
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't want my answer to get too long and complicated, so I really appreciate you showing this separately. :)